# Victory in the face of defeat - - what does this phrase mean?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I have seen this phrase being used multiple times, mostly in the written context. But I am unsure what exactly it means to have

> Victory *in the face of* defeat

I am confused between these 2 interpretations

1. To gain victory even when defeat was close?
2. To be victorious in some broader sense, *in spite of the defeat*?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide some examples, with context.

Comment: Consider these two examples. 


1. The experimental medication worked for his cancer, and he fought through to his wellness. He found victory in the face of defeat.
2. She worked harder for the next 6 months resulting in a sooner death but she finished the book she always dreamt of. That was her victory in the face of defeat.

Comment: So, how would you interpret those?

Comment: In the very order I wrote the interpretations.

Comment: Of course, those were examples you contrived.  The usage is not particularly idiomatic.  Do you have any real examples derived from print?

Comment: Understand that the idioms "snatch victory from the jaws of defeat" and (ironically) "snatch defeat from the jaws of victory" are moderately common and have reasonably agreed-to meanings.

Comment: Umm sorry i didn't come across this in writing now.

Comment: @HotLicks Your complaint is badly taken. If you really doubted its use, you could have googled and seen that it is, in fact, common enough among badly-educated seminarians. What *is* surprising is that only the ironic version of your expression ever actually took off. The straight version never seems to have actually preceded it, but can be backformed now. [See ngram below.]

Comment: My Ngram of "victory from the jaws" and "defeat from the jaws" shows victory well in the lead from 1860 on.

Comment: Ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=victory+from+the+jaws%2C+defeat+from+the+jaws&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvictory%20from%20the%20jaws%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdefeat%20from%20the%20jaws%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

> **[in the face of](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/67425)**

just means *in the presence of* or *confronted with* and so both of your senses could work and therefore probably are sometimes used. Google seems to think that Christian pastors are the most conspicuous users of the infelicitous phrase and that they use it to mean your second sense, very particularly that religion gives you a true victory in the face of the seeming defeat of death.

Really, the better expression for your first sense is

> **snatching victory from the jaws of defeat**

which implies the very visceral closeness of disaster. Having said that, almost no one says that. [What people actually use](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=victory+in+the+face+of%2Csnatch+defeat+from+the+jaws%2Csnatch+victory+from+the+jaws+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) is its humorously ironic inverse,

> **snatching defeat from the jaws of victory**

which naturally implies that one done f'ed up and scored an own-goal.

Comment: That's a handy link. Thanks. So my take away is that the 2nd interpretation is valid. I will look for its usage in established texts to confirm.

Comment: @iammrigank **NO**. That is not what I said at all. It's how the people on the first result page of Google are using it but that's just how they are using it. The phrase isn't a pat expression, so it could be taken *in either sense*. You should just figure it out from context or avoid it in your writing.

Comment: Okay... *Either sense* then. Or better yet depending on the context. Thank you.

Comment: Had you entered the Ngram correctly (or at least read the warning message) you'd see that "snatch victory" was more popular than "snatch defeat" in the beginning, and more recently the two have been about equal.  And "victory in the face of" hardly ever refers to defeat -- much more often "overwhelming odds" or some such.

Comment: (And your OED link routes to a pay wall.)

Comment: @HotLicks The OED link goes directly to the entry, which is much more thorough than dictionary.com or Wiktionary. (If you don't support the *OED*, though I'd advocate doing so, you can still easily poke around online and find institutional access.) Hard to think of a good reason not to provide your ngram links, if you went to the trouble of finding some supporting evidence.

Comment: I put more effort into Ngram than you did.  Delete "of" from the "snatch victory" string and try again.  Then examine some of the references at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Definition of “snatch victory (from the jaws of defeat)” - English Dictionary

“snatch victory (from the jaws of defeat)” in British English

**snatch victory (from the jaws of defeat)**
​

> to win at the last moment possible, when it had previously seemed
>   certain that you were going to lose

(Definition of “snatch victory (from the jaws of defeat)” from the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus © Cambridge University Press)

The critical aspect of the definition is that defeat was imminent.

In the ironic sense (there's been a lot of word play on this phrase), "snatch defeat from the jaws of victory," the team or individual or country has been close to an almost-certain victory, but nevertheless loses.

What you call a second sense--obtain some kind of victory in spite of losing--is not part of either one of these phrases.